# SQL MERGE - when not matched insert by using select table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible, if not exists then I will insert my data using select? I'm using user-defined table to which is the `@ProcessItem` variable to insert all the non-existing.

```
MERGE INTO EmpClearancePendingItems1 a
USING @ProcessItem b ON a.OnProcessItem = b.OnProcessItem
                     AND a.TranNo = @TranNo

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET a.Amount = b.Amount,
            a.Remarks = b.Remarks,
            a.IfOthers = b.IfOthers

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (UserID, OnProcessItem, Amount, Remarks, TranNo, IfOthers)
    VALUES (SELECT @ResignEmp, OnProcessItem, Amount, Remarks, @TranNo, IfOthers
            FROM @ProcessItem);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since most of your values are columns from the source table anyway - I don't see any reason why you would need a `SELECT` in the `INSERT` - just try this:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (UserID, OnProcessItem, Amount, Remarks, TranNo, IfOthers)
    VALUES (@ResignEmp, b.OnProcessItem, b.Amount, b.Remarks, @TranNo, b.IfOthers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Merge operation is acting on row by row basis and as per [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#syntax), only VALUES clause is supported for WHEN NOT MATCHED. You don't need SELECT clause and also, syntax does not support it also.

```
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_not_matched> ]  


 <merge_not_matched>::=   {  
     INSERT [ ( column_list ) ]
         { VALUES ( values_list )  
         | DEFAULT VALUES }   }
```

Below would suffice:

```sql
INSERT (UserID, OnProcessItem, Amount, Remarks, TranNo, IfOthers)
    VALUES (@ResignEmp, OnProcessItem, Amount, Remarks, @TranNo, IfOthers)
```